# away3D 4.x export as awd format not include sequences information

Tags: away3d

I created a character model in 3dmax2012, and added lots of animations in the model.
I tried to export that model into .awd format,and named "hero.awd", then I used prebab3D  software to open hero.awd, and checked it processes log, I found that it does not include 
"sequences.txt" information, so I cannot control model's animations.

Comment: Have you tried this http://away3d.com/example/3ds_Max_workflow

Comment: I have tried it.and I have tried to created a new model for the same programm,It can not control model's animations.I don't know how to add lots of animations in the model for away3d?